# C++ Arrays and Vectors

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and this is not really part of my major so I am a little lost! If I can contact anyone personally for help please let me know :) 
My program will need to read in ten integer values from a file, and store them in an array or vector. The reading of the values should be done in a separate function that takes an integer array as a parameter, and read from a file named tempInput.txt. I am unsure how to create an integer array as a parameter. 
Then, from main, you will call another function, whose signature and return type is thus:

```
bool isDangerous(int tempArray[ ]);
```

If you could help me with part one or two that would be great!

```
namespace std;
int divison(int,int);
int main()
{
    void readData(int tempArray[ ]);

    int tempInput[10];
    readData(tempInput);

    //int size=10;              //Array size

    int sum =0;
    //for(int i=0;i<size;i++)   //Loop which inputs arrays data and
    // {
            //cout << myArray[i] << endl;
    // }

    return 0;     
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there, not as a comment

Comment: What does the file tempInput.txt look like?  Do you read the ten integer values into the array that's being passed in?  What do you have so far?  Please try to be more descriptive :)

Comment: The text file contains 10 numbers 100
68
78
99
94
106
80
82
106
101     and i have to find the average of the sum and if the sum is greater than 100 there will be a specific out put

Comment: sorry the code looks so strange im having a hard time formatting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can understand the question, here's some code to get you started (Note that I haven't filled in everything exactly, I don't want to do your work for you)

```
#include<fstream> //So we can read from files
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void readData(int tempArray []) {
    //Open file and read data into temp array
    //If you need help reading data, see:
    //http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
}

bool isDangerous(int tempArray []) {
    //Do things
}

int main() {
    int tempInput [10];
    readData(tempInput);  //Read the data into tempInput
    bool result;
    result = isDangerous(tempInput);  //Do something with isDangerous
    return 0;
}
```